# Laravel controller method for router with an optional parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'd like to have a controller handling url like .../item/list and .../item/list/5.
First one would be to display all items, second one would display items whose author has an ID = 5.

```
public function getList($userid) {
    $items = \DB::table('items')->get();
    if ($userid) $items = \DB::table('items')->where('user_id', '=', $userid)->get();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

URL like `.../item` has an argument missing.
Is there option to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your route looks like this:

```
Route::get('item/{userid}', 'MyController@getList');
```

But what should happen if there is no id?
Let's change your logic like this:
If there is a userId in the url then display the user's items. If there is no id display all.

So change your route:

```
Route::get('item/{userid?}', 'MyController@getList');
```

And also your function:

```
public function getList($userid = null) {
    $items = \DB::table('items')->get();
    if ($userid) $items = \DB::table('items')->where('user_id', '=', $userid)->get();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a route with an optional parameter

```
Route::get('item/list/{userid}', 'MyController@getList');
```

Then change `userid` in your function to have a default argument value

```
public function getList($userid = '') {
    $query = \DB::table('items');
    if ($userid) {
        $query->where('user_id', '=', $userid);
    }
    $items = $query->get();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // ...
    }
}
```